# C# Ordering Collection by Unknown Properties

Tags: c#, .net

How can I order a list of objects by unknown number of values? Using LINQ it will something like this:

```
var myNewCollection = myCollection.OrderBy(c => c.Id).ThenBy(c => c.Name).ThenBy(c => c.Years).ToList();
```

And I have a list of 11 properties the user can sort by. When I don't know how many fields the use will select, how can I build my expression in this instance?

Comment: Check this out. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add nuget package ... `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core`

This is the site with the documentation ... https://dynamic-linq.net/

You need to build a string which looks something like this ... `Id ASC, Name DESC, Years ASC` ... as per the documentation, or, straight sorting without the direction, e.g. `Id, Name, Years`.  Then simply call the OrderBy method (https://dynamic-linq.net/basic-simple-query#ordering-results) ...

```
var sortBy = "Id, Name, Years";

var result = DynamicQueryableExtensions.OrderBy(data.AsQueryable(), sortBy).ToList();
```

If required, you'll need to do the fancy footwork to make the selection the user sees more useful than the name of your fields.